# Erro: error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java

Por que meu código está dando o erro:

> error: class, interface, or enum expected

Segue o código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class teste175 {

        public static void main (String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

            int a, i;
            a = sc.nextInt();

            int v[] = new int [a];

            for (i=0; i<a; i++) {
                v[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            funcao (v, a);
        }
    }

    static int funcao (int v[], int a){

        int temp, j, i;

        for (j=0; j<a; j++){
            for (i=1; i<a; i++){

                if (v[i]<v[i-1] {
                    temp = v[i];
                    v[i] = v[i-1];
                    v[i-1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma dica, adicione o código identado, facilita a leitura dele, caso o problema seja simples. E outra, não adianta jogar o código aqui e esperar que alguém descubra onde o erro ocorreu, alem do código, de preferencia indentado, aponte sempre onde o erro ocorre no código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos principais motivos para você sempre estar em dificuldade para entender o que está acontecendo no código é a falta de organização deles. Olhando esse código realmente é muito difícil achar um erro aí, até mesmo para programadores bem experientes. Organizando ele fica bem fácil achar todos os erros presentes no código, não só o relatado. Isso vale para todos seus código, em Java, C++ ou outra linguagem.

A função está fora da classe, faltam parênteses, tem retorno errado, só para citar alguns problemas. Assim é bem mais simples e mais fácil de ler:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int[] v = new int[a];
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) v[i] = sc.nextInt();
        funcao(v);
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) System.out.println(v[i]);
    }

    static void funcao(int[] v) {
        for (int j = 1; j < v.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 1; i < v.length; i++) {
                if (v[i] < v[i - 1]) {
                    int temp = v[i];
                    v[i] = v[i - 1];
                    v[i - 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/HqAO39). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/awhufqdc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/InClass.java).

Nem vou entrar no mérito do algoritmo ser bom ou ruim, não sei o objetivo.

Comment: eu uso o gedit do ubuntu pra escrever os códigos, você sabe alguma ferramenta que me ajude nesse sentido no próprio linux? obrigado desde já

Comment: Nenhum editor vai organizar seus códigos, isso quem tem que fazer é você. Tem um monte de editor ou IDE que pode ajudar um pouquinho. O objetivo aqui não é recomendar nada, mas se procurar por Eclipse, NetBeans, Code::Blocks vai achar algo um pouco melhor. Tem gente que não quer instalar tudo isso e usa outras coisas, como o Sublime.