# Função que inverte os valores do vetor em outro vetor

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

            public class ativ15 {

                public static void main (String[] args) {

                Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

                int i;
                int A[] = new int [10];
                int B[] = new int [A.length];

                System.out.println ("Digite os elementos do vetor: ");

                for (i=0; i<10; i++){               
                A[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }

                GeraInverso (A, B);

        }

                static void GeraInverso (int A[], int B[]) {

                int i, temp;

                for (i=0; i<A.length; i++){
                B[i] = A[i];
            }

                for (i=0; i<10; i++) {

                if (i<5) {
                temp = B[i];
                B[i] = B[10-i-1];
                B[10-i-1] = temp;
                }
            }                                           

       }

}
```

Preciso que a função main imprima o valor do vetor B (a funcao GeraInverso inverte os valores do vetor A e copia para o vetor B). Para isso o que a função GeraInverso deve retornar? Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há necessidade de devolver nada. Vetores em Java são passados por referência, logo as alterações ocorridas em `GeraInverso` são refletidas no `main`.

Comment: então como eu faço pra imprimir o vetor na função main? porque eu ja tentei de algumas formas e dão diferentes erros

Comment: Faça como você fez para lê-lo: um laço. E imprima `B[i]`

Comment: estava faltando um } que gerou varios erros. Obrigado!

Comment: @Leko a resposta anterior, que aparentemente você não gostou, mostra tudo isso que quer saber aqui, que não foi respondido e você gostou: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164296/101